# Is there a way to remove entries based on condition in =filter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Image of google sheets:

[image: 1]

I probably did not phrase my question accurately. Is there a way to remove the result `'a'` because it fulfils the `'<>1'` condition? I am pretty sure a mixture of query and arrayformula is needed but I can't figure it out.

I am aware I can split it into multiple columns to achieve what I want but I am looking for a solution that requires only 1 formula.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful here, but if I understand your screenshot correctly you should be able to do this easily with the QUERY or FILTER function. Below is a query sample that would satisfy your >3 filter requirement

```
=QUERY(A1:B20, "SELECT B WHERE A > 3")
```

Where A1:B20 is your data range